# Building Spark filter query dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have multiple entries in a map with (column name, value). Now i want to filter a dataset which has column names, and this column name is there is the map as a key, and the value defines the value that particular column name of dataset should have.

For example, dataset has columns (a,b,c) and map has entries {(a,1),(b,2)}

Now i want to filter the dataset for columns with a as 1 and b as 2.

What is a way to achieve this in spark using java?

Comment: Please post what you have tried. The description of your problem is pretty vague but if I'm understanding it correctly, I'd try to iterate over the map with a for loop and then inside the loop select the column that you want using the key of the current iteration then filter the column with the value. You can then union the dataframes back together at the end if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If dataset means DataFrame, and Map values only Ints,
such code can be used:

```
    val parametersMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
        // condition: a=1 AND b=2
    val condition = parametersMap.foldLeft("")((result, entry) => result + " AND " + entry._1 + "=" + entry._2).substring(4)
    val result = dataFrame.filter(condition)
```